# c# My codes keep running after closing the winform

Tags: c#, dialog

I have many forms and I manage them on my Main form . I open the other forms with ShowDialog() and some of my forms that involve a operation that happens with timer keeps running after closing the dialog and I use

this.Close();

for closing the showdialog but it still works behind and then gives me the messagebox.show while ı m on my main form . I mean it does it work as if it is still active but I closed dialog?

The code below is just one of them it works with task await and my other forms runs with timer and I get the same problem for them too.

```
private async void ıconButton4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        saniye = 0;


        if (hız <= 29)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Başlamadan önce hızı da belirlemeliyiz", "Hız belirtilmedi", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        else
        {
            buttondurdur.Enabled = true;

            button1.Enabled = false;
            button2.Enabled = false;

            menuStrip1.Enabled = false;

            richTextBox1.Text = string.Empty;


            TextFormatFlags flags = TextFormatFlags.Top | TextFormatFlags.Left |
                                    TextFormatFlags.WordBreak | TextFormatFlags.NoPadding |
                                    TextFormatFlags.TextBoxControl;

            timer1.Enabled = true;


            foreach (var word in GetWords())
            {
                richTextBox1.Text += (word + ' ');
                kelimesayısı += 1;
                do
                {
                    await Task.Delay(hız);
                } while (_isPaused);



                Size textSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText(richTextBox1.Text, richTextBox1.Font, richTextBox1.Size, flags);


                if (textSize.Height >= (richTextBox1.Height - 40))
                {
                    richTextBox1.Clear();
                }


            }




            if (Saying.Length >= 150)
            {
                timer1.Stop();
                MessageBox.Show("Okuma hızınız dakikada " + (kelimesayısı * 60) / saniye + " kelime ");
                timer1.Enabled = false;
                richTextBox1.Clear();
                button1.Enabled = false;
                button2.Enabled = true;
                buttondurdur.Enabled = false;
                Saying = string.Empty;
                kelimesayısı = 0;

                menuStrip1.Enabled = true;
                saniye = 0;

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Seçilen metin çok kısa ", "Uyarı", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                timer1.Enabled = false;
                richTextBox1.Clear();                
                buttondurdur.Enabled = false;
                Saying = string.Empty;
                saniye = 0;
                kelimesayısı = 0;

                button1.Enabled = true;
                button2.Enabled = true;

                menuStrip1.Enabled = true;
            }
        }




    }
```

Comment: Did you know, you're allowed to rename controls after you drop them on a form~? You should rename them, as code where every control is called some variation of `controltypeN` is really hard to understand. Can you imagine how hard C# would be to use if Microsoft took the same strategy and instead of `string.Length` or `string.Contains`/`string.StartsWith` you just had `string.IntProperty1`, `string.BoolReturningMethod1`/`string.BoolReturningMethod2` ?

Comment: Do you have a question? If you want the timer to stop working when you close the form, call `Stop` on the timer and then set `Enabled=false;`

Comment: I tried using timer1.stop and then enabled=false but it doesn't work code still runs behind

Comment: Break the execution in visual studio and find out what code is running. If you simply close a form it doesn't mean that it stops executing code. For example where do you exit your `while (_isPaused)` loop?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try `this.Dispose();`, instead of `this.Close();`. Although it's a worse solution, in this case it may work better.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I meant in my comment.

I created a simple forms app, added a button to the main form and run this as the button handler:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var dlg = new TheDialog())
    {
        if (dlg.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("OK");
        }
    }
}
```

Then I wrote the `TheDialog` Form class (built with the intention of being run non-modally with `ShowDialog`).

I added three buttons, one labeled "Start Timer", and the other two the standard OK and Cancel buttons for a non-modal form (setting them as the Accept and Cancel buttons for the form).  I also dropped a Timer on the the dialog's form, setting its time to 15 seconds (15000 ms).  Here are the button handlers:

```
private void StartTimerBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (timer1.Enabled)
    {
        timer1.Stop();
    }
    timer1.Start();
}

private void CancelBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
    Close();
}

private void OkBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    Close();
}
```

I wired up the Timer's `Tick` event to:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Timer Expired");
    timer1.Stop();
}
```

So, if you bring up the form, press "Start Timer" and count to 15, a message box will pop up saying "Timer Expired"

Finally, I wired up the dialog's `FormClosing` event.  This will get called right before the form closes - whether it's because someone pressed the [x] in the upper right corner or that person pressed the `OK` or `Cancel` buttons (or pressed [ESC] or [Enter]).

```
private void TheDialog_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (timer1.Enabled)
    {
        timer1.Stop();
    }
}
```

That way, no matter what happens, when the dialog closes, the timer will stop.

For what it's worth, just calling `Dispose` is a real bad idea.  Accessing a disposed object is never a good idea - you need to stop it first.  When the form is disposed, the controls that you added to the form in the designer will be disposed.

It's also worth noting that this is what's really meant by a [Minimal Reproduceable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)